# Выбор библиотеки Python для работы с Excel

Tags: python, excel, поиск-библиотек

Есть несколько больших библиотек для работы Python 3.9.0 с файлами Excel, которые на первый взгляд обладают схожим функционалом. Подскажите пожалуйста, какая библиотека на данный момент наиболее удобна и функциональна?

Требуется выборка данных из листов таблицы Excel 2019 (формат .xlsx) и внесение данных в таблицу. В дальнейшем планируется работа с формулами в таблицах, а также работа с форматом .csv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для простой работы с данными (без формул и графиков) достаточно использовать Pandas, который сам под капотом использует либо [xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) либо [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html).

Для более глубокой работы с Excel можно использовать [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) и [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html) - это самые продвинутые и самые популярные модули для работы с Excel.